# Accessing website hosted in a linux container from windows host

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-for-windows, linux-containers

I have a linux container based on latest `ruby` image hosted in my windows laptop. I have a sample website running in the container. I can confirm that the website is running fine because running `curl http://localhost:4000` with in the container returns the expected html. However, when I try to access the url from a browser in Windows it fails saying that it is not reachable. I am trying to figure out a way to access the sample app using browser in Windows.

Though I am trying to setup a ruby container (as I am trying to learn ruby), I am suspecting this is a networking problem with LCOW because I cannot `ping` the ip address of the container from Windows command prompt. It gives the error that "**TTL expired in transit**". Has anyone ever successfully tried a linux container on windows and accessing the website hosted in the container from windows? Could you please help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong or if I have to do something extra, like network route configuration, to make this working?

**Further Details**:

1. Docker version: 19.03.4
2. Host: Windows 10 Business Edition
3. Base Image: [ruby on linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby)
4. docker run command used:

   `docker run -dit -p 4000:4000 --rm --name test updatedRubyImage`
5. updatedRubyImage: This is a new image I created using base image. I installed a few `gems` on top of the base and commited it as a new image.

Comment: Use host=0.0.0.0 in your web application when you are starting the server. This makes your server listen on all network interfaces in your container not just localhost.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I am not familiar with Linux or Ruby. Could you please tell me where and how I make this change?